# I want to set my homepage like this /#projects asp.net mvc

Tags: routeconfig

I want to set my homepage like this /#projects asp.net mvc.
on route config file i tried some options but didnt manage to solve it yet

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",

            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set my homepage like this /#projects asp.net mvc.

You can't.

Most browsers do not pass anything after the `#` (fragments are what they are called) to the server, so there is no reliable way for MVC routing (or any other server-side web technology) to read them.

You can *generate* URLs on the server with fragments but since it is not possible for MVC to read them, there are limited uses for using fragments in MVC.

You *can* use fragments in client-side routing (using a JavaScript framework of some sort), but not in server-side routing.